# Javascript - Regular Expression

Tags: regex

I need to check the following strings.

6130  - (Office Configuration]

6130 - Office Configuration

6130 - [Office Configuration

Need to extract number and the string along with the ( or [ and need to omit all the non word characters in between the number and the string

For Ex: 6130 - Office Configuration, extract group **6130** and **Office Configuration**

6130 **%&%&-** Office Configuration ==> **6130**  & **Office Configuration**

And i have tried using the below pattern.

```
var pattern=/(\d+)?(\W*)(\[|\()(.*)/gim;
```

It will match the first and the third. But not the second. As it is used for the parsing , please do not change the grouping that I have added

Comment: Are these three strings the only valid versions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This matches your 3 samples, but you may want to be more specific also about what patterns should NOT match, and modify the expression accordingly

```
^\d{4} - [(\[]?[\w\s]*\]?$
```

Answer (score 1):

I suggest this improved pattern instead with sharper boundaries and non-capturing groups:

[`^(\d+)?(?:\s+-\s+)(?:[\(\[])?([\w\s]+)(?:[\]\)])?$`](https://regex101.com/r/ELy3cX/2)

Answer (score -1):

Almost right.  You are missing a test for the null character at the start of the name string.

(\d+)\s+-\s+([|(|)(.*?)(]|)|)$

Here is a nice tool for testing regexes

https://regex101.com/r/vuV2tO/2

Comment: This doesn't match the above three strings.

Comment: What exactly is the problem ?  The regex checker in the link seems to think it does.

Comment: One of the strings ends with a closing square bracket.  Does your regex capture this?

Comment: The .* in the final group catches everything to the end.  The original question didnt differentiate the last character either.  Easy enough to add another group at the end (]|)|).

Comment: It's not that easy actually, because only one string pattern has this closing bracket.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/157252/discussion-between-fluoresce-and-tim-biegeleisen).

Comment: no it not working :(. want to omit  all non word characters except the [ or ( that come along with the string

Comment: try the updated regex (and link).  It removes the final character (if any) into it's own match group.

Comment: https://regex101.com/r/HVIfxL/1 check this . Its not matching. Not space is the only character i expect there

Comment: https://regex101.com/r/HVIfxL/2 - you didnt specify that the dash could be other characters in your question.

Comment: for that i have put (\W*) in the regexp :)

Answer (score -2):

I modified your expression only to let you understand what is missing in your expression:

-You missed the number of occurrences of '(' or '[' or ']' or ')'
So I used the * of each special character occurrence (before & after string).

```
var pattern = /(\d+)?(\W*)(\[|\()*(.*)(\]|\))*/;
```